# Proof by Induction for $X=\frac{n}{3n+1}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, induction

The question asks to prove that the set $X=\{\frac{n}{3n+1}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ does not contain a maximal element. Also prove that the set does not contain a minimum.

I started with the equation $X_n=\frac{n}{3n+1}$ and a base case of $n=1$. Doing so, $X_1=\frac{1}{4}$. Now I take $n=k$ which gives us $X_k=\frac{k}{3k+1}$. Doing so, we then want to prove that $n=k+1$ is also true. So, if we plug this into the equation, we get $X_{k+1}=\frac{k+1}{3k+2}$.

After doing so, I got stuck and did not know how to continue with this question. Any help would be tremendously appreciated.

Comment: You want to prove that each entry is smaller than the next.  Is $\frac{n}{3n+1}<\frac{(n+1)}{3(n+1)+1}$ for each $n$?  Try cross multiplying...

Comment: Isn't $X_0 = 0$ the minimum?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I wouldn't proceed by induction if I were you. Here are some hints on how to solve it:

- Consider the case in which $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is very large. Then intuitively the quantities $3n+1$ and $3n$ have comparably the same size (in the sense that $\frac{3n+1}{3n}= 1+\frac{1}{3n}$ is very close to 1) and therefore we might think that $\frac{n}{3n+1}\sim \frac{n}{3n}=\frac{1}{3}$.
- So $\frac{1}{3}$ is a candidate for an extremum. You might want to check if it holds true that $\frac{n}{3n+1}\leq\frac{1}{3}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
- Regarding the infimum, I think there should be a typo somewhere in the exercise. In facts, if you take $n=0$, then you get $X_0=0$; moreover, for all $n$ we have $\frac{n}{3n+1}\geq 0$, so $0$ would be the minimum of such set. Maybe the set was defined for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Strict inequality, $\frac{n}{3n+1}\lneq \frac{1}{3}$

Comment: Yes sorry, i forgot to say that the inequality is actually strict and therefore it is a supremum, but not a maximum.

Answer (score 0):

Simply show, in this case, that $X_1$ is not a maximal and that $X_n$ not being maximal implies $X_{n+1}$ is not maximal.

It is obvious that $X_1$ is not maximal as $X_1 = \frac14, X_2=\frac27$ and thus $X_2>X_1$.

The next part is slightly harder: we must show that $X_{n+1}>X_n$ holds for all $n\in\Bbb N$:

$$X_{n+1}>X_n\\\implies\frac{n+1}{3(n+1)+1}>\frac{n}{3n+1}\\\implies
(3n+4)(3n+1)>n(n+1)\\\implies9n^2+15n+4>n^2+n\\\implies
8n^2+14n+4>0.$$

This final inequality is obvious as $n\in\Bbb N$.

Can you do the final step of linking this back to showing the nonexistence of a maximal element in the sequence? What about proving the minimal element?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another proof that $X_{n+1} > X_n$ for all $n$ (be they natural numbers or integers).

Let $f(x) = \frac{x}{3x+1}$.  Then $X_n = f(n)$ for all $n$.  For any $n$,
$$
    X_{n+1} - X_n = f(n+1) - f(n) = f'(c_n)
$$
for some $c_n$ between $n$ and $n+1$.  This follows from the Mean Value Theorem.  But $f'(x) = \frac{1}{(3x+1)^2}$, which is positive for all $x$.  So $f'(c_n) > 0$, which implies $X_{n+1} > X_n$.